Error running a python exe (made with nuitka)
i compiled a python code into executable in my machine using nuitka and it works fine. However, when I try to run the exe file from another computer I get this system level error:
E:\app\main.dist>main.exe

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "E:\app\MAIN~1.DIS\main.py", line 1, in <module>

  File "E:\app\MAIN~1.DIS\requests\__init__.py", line 43, in <module requests>



  File "E:\app\MAIN~1.DIS\urllib3\__init__.py", line 11, in <module urllib3>

  File "E:\app\MAIN~1.DIS\urllib3\exceptions.py", line 3, in <module urllib3.e

xceptions>

  File "E:\app\MAIN~1.DIS\urllib3\packages\six.py", line 234, in create_module



  File "E:\app\MAIN~1.DIS\urllib3\packages\six.py", line 209, in load_module

  File "E:\app\MAIN~1.DIS\urllib3\packages\six.py", line 118, in _resolve

  File "E:\app\MAIN~1.DIS\urllib3\packages\six.py", line 87, in _import_module



  File "E:\app\MAIN~1.DIS\http\client.py", line 76, in <module>

  File "E:\app\MAIN~1.DIS\socket.py", line 49, in <module>

ImportError: LoadLibraryExW 'E:\app\MAIN~1.DIS\_socket.pyd' failed: The parame

ter is incorrect.



Please note that i have copied all the folders and files created by nuitka to my other computer before running (main.build, main.dist, .env, main.spec).
Anyone with a solution? Please help.
Btw, the operating system in which i compiled and ran where Windows 7 home and Windows 7 ultimate respectively (both 64 bit). I also tried pyinstaller and it was giving the same error.

What flags did you use in nuitka and pyinstaller? If you still use --onefile try using this flag for pyinstaller:
--collect-submodules socket.pyd


I didn't use any flags. I didn't do a --onefile compilation either. Will try as you mentioned

Tried but this time the error message was different:                            E:\app\dist>main.exe
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "PyInstaller\hooks\rthooks\pyi_rth_multiprocessing.py", line 107, in 
File "PyInstaller\hooks\rthooks\pyi_rth_multiprocessing.py", line 18, in pyi
rthook
File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 419, in exec_module
File "multiprocessing_init_.py", line 16, in 
File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 419, in exec_module

File "multiprocessing\context.py", line 6, in 
File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 419, in exec_module
File "multiprocessing\reduction.py", line 16, in 
File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 419, in exec_module
File "socket.py", line 49, in 
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _socket: The parameter is incorrect
.
[2872] Failed to execute script 'pyi_rth_multiprocessing' due to unhandled excep
tion!

Reinstall python in version 3.12 and all pips and if possible try to compile the exe on windows 10. Also edit your question with the problematic code I will try to compile on my PC.

Sorry, but the code is a part of a closed source project which is not allowed to share. And yeah, firstly I compiled it in windows 10 but then too the same error comes. I came to the conclusion that it could only be run in windows 10 and chose to rewrite it in golang again, and now it's working. Thanks for help anyways.

Do you have an "E:" drive in your other computer? If not, maybe that is the reason. If it doesn't have an E: drive, it cannot find the program's scripts because that was where the program was originally made.
"
File "E:\app\MAIN~1.DIS\main.py", line 1, in 
File "E:\app\MAIN~1.DIS\requests_init_.py", line 43, in 
"
Try making it in your C: Drive instead and then in your other computer, download it and open it in your C: Drive.
(This might be wrong)

No, all the files (main.dist, main build, .env, etc) are inside the E: drive. I don't have an E drive in the computer with which I compiled it, but nuitka auto detects my current dir so that can't be the problem I think.

Tried but unfortunately it didn't work :(
